# NPM 6 - Should I audit fix all package vulnerabilities?

Tags: security, npm, npm-install, audit, angular6

After installing NPM 6 almost every NPM package that I install on an Angular 6 project has vulnerabilities.

Should I "npm audit fix" every package each time?
Should I reinstall NPM 5? Other solution?

This is the terminal sequlize code I used with its vulnerabilities:

```
npm i sequelize --save
npm WARN @angular/material@6.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/cdk@6.2.1 
but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ sequelize@4.37.10
added 16 packages from 39 contributors and audited 22308 packages in 
10.659s
found 9 vulnerabilities (3 low, 5 moderate, 1 high)
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Answer (score 0):

Try performing the below cmd's : 
* npm i karma@3.0.0 --save and 
* npm install --save-dev protractor@5.4.0

Comment: Can you explain why this helps?